# Typescript Types - question about composite types using infer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

Using redux, I ended up writing the following snippet in my store code:

```js
type CombinedParamTypes<T extends {
    [key: string]: (state: any, action: any) => any;
}> = T extends {
    [key: string]: (state: infer R, action: any) => any;
} ? R : never;

type CombinedReturnTypes<T extends {
    [key: string]: (...args: any) => any;
}> = T extends {
    [key: string]: (...args) => infer R;
} ? R : never;
```

Example:

```js
import camera from "./camera/reducer";
import settings from "./settings/reducer";

export const ALL_REDUCERS = {
    camera,
    settings,
};

const COMBINED_REDUCERS = combineReducers(ALL_REDUCERS);

export type FlatReduxState = CombinedParamTypes<typeof ALL_REDUCERS>;
// returns intersection type: ICameraState & ISettingsState

export type WhyDifferent = CombinedReturnTypes<typeof ALL_REDUCERS>;
// returns union type: ICameraState | ISettingsState
```

Can anyone explain why they are returning differently? I realize one is looking at a parameter and the other is looking at the return type, but how does that translate into deciding intersection vs union?

Comment: Asking what parameter would need to be used to call a union of functions will always be a intersection of the parameter type.

I.E  if i ask typescript what parameter do i need to call a union of functions F1 and F2 it will be the arguments of F1 & F2

This is not the same when it comes to ReturnType if i ask typescript what is the ReturnType of F1 | F2 it will be the a union of  return types, because it will be either not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function types are [covariant in their return type and contravariant in the argument types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types). Concerning [type inference in conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) this is also stated in the docs:

> [...] multiple candidates for the same type variable in co-variant positions causes a union type to be inferred [...] Likewise, multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred[.]

For your reducer return type that means, TypeScript infers the common *supertype* of all instantiations of `R`, which results in an union type of return types - `ICameraState | ISettingsState`. The other way around, all instantiations of `R` in your function parameters of `CombinedParamTypes` are combined as intersection type to get a common *subtype* for `R` - `ICameraState & ISettingsState`.

The underlying concept of covariance and contravariance is sometimes a bit difficult to grasp when you hear it the first (and second - speaking for me...) time. Covariance in a sens means, that the subtyping relation of basic component types is preserved, when each of them is packed in a more complex type (higher order type/HOT) like a function, list or others. Contravariance is the inverse - a subtype becomes the supertype in a HOT, because a function is contravariant in its argument types.

Simple example following the dogs and animals analogy of [this recommended  article](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance):

```
type Animal = {
  sex: "m" | "w";
};

type Dog = {
  bark(): void;
};

declare const animals: {
  aDog: (d: Dog) => string;
  anAnimal: (a: Animal) => number;
};

// string | number is the supertype of all given return types (covariance)
type ReturnTypes = CombinedReturnTypes<typeof animals>; // string | number

// Dog & Animal is the subtype of all given function parameter types (contravariance)
type Params = CombinedParamTypes<typeof animals>; // Dog & Animal

function testCombinedParamTypes(arg: (p: Params) => void) {
  // assumes that the argument of callback is Dog AND Animal...
  arg({ sex: "m", bark: () => "wuff" });
}

function client() {
  // ... so it is safe for a client to pass in a callback
  // that deals only with a Dog XOR Animal (see the original typeof animals   
  // type from which Params is derived). E.g. Dog being a super type of Dog & Animal 
  // can be safely passed as argument in a contravariant position 
  testCombinedParamTypes((dog: Dog) => {});
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgSwLYEMA2UC8UDeAoKKAZwgA8AuKAIiSqgB9qB3KgbjwF929RIoARAPYBzLLgJQARigBOAawAUASkoA3QQgAm7Lnh7hoAYUFJJCOBE0AFWSiQAVA0QA8E+1DLAIcTUXGFCAG05CBBKImAZc2EAXUoFCJQvShQ4EAAaKBQAY2AEQTgUtKUsAD4stPZCDjxy7HdPb19-KGDQ8MjouKgE4CSISnMAMwgZKAAlTJy8gqKQEsxy1JAdCQB+CYlKC1VR7l4jEzMLTXGIYABXGThHSBc3D1IvHz98ANaQsOJOuFj4gDpAbJhEQ5gslpUJDU6lAGk8mq8JG0vhEor9ugpAf9gaCKvMylBhqMJqtCBtxlsoDs9npNBBsmhZNBsgUIhVkOhcW8skJhPFNJReeDvmjhFUKvAOWh4ihKJLUGhhXALqYabo8AB6DUi6IMKkqyTEhB+YAAC2gRAukBkByggiGWTQGGECF2cCgMnOV3dBz8ChZqlkCFS2QgSn0fDOl2utwgfmwxlM5ksUe9sZcB3t7IVRFKrCgWqgtvsAEYxKjdYxlaqZHpC7yoAAyWCIBWEk3m4gXSS2rPoZ2u7xQIYXOC5fLusC2JDnYm+nosuCRFCBqIhsMR6A2GR2eNQRPHSzbuzp5yZh2pKW5-OF4sAJjEDeb8vQehHY5mPrjwAPyes0-TBRgXiMBKGPJAiGFdQtBKblCxQIhLRnDskiLTtgRVbxgDtB1sn7aRsjkdsBBEWAADl+BbKUsQkYEFBwYgyEoGgqEyaR5HiYUqCYC4hiGOgOCUVY8HfccCigBkECw5QWkLLFiEETIEGw41iBQEZh0EMZUkJOB1DkXVJKwotBCgKdEN0rIJPwnI5AkW9TVQulOTtOA0BAKAmGU00rIbAANAB5cYKiohV-gkLwIl-E5wMAhRNBEQURGFHBBNWIA)

Hope, I could clear things up a bit.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! Your "type inference in conditional types" URL is not working, though.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the link in the answer.